# Add the test of the Proportional Hazards Assumption of a Cox Regression to gtsummary table

Tags: gtsummary, gt

I would like to add a column with the p-value of the proportional hazards assumption test of a Cox regression to a gtsummary table. I don't think this option is available directly with the package.
Here is an example using the survival package :

```
tbl_regression_ex1 <-
    coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ age + marker, trial) %>%
    tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

```
zph <- coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ age + marker, trial)
cox.zph(zph, terms = FALSE, global = FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `modify_table_body()` function to merge any additional results you'd like into the main `tbl_regression()` table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

mod <- coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ age + marker, trial)

# convert test results into data frame to merge with tbl_regressoin table
ph_test <- 
  cox.zph(mod, terms = FALSE, global = FALSE) %>%
  purrr::pluck("table") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("variable") %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  select(variable, ph.test_p.value = p) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    # add a column for merging with gtsummary table
    row_type = "label",
    # format p-value
    ph.test_p.value = style_pvalue(ph.test_p.value)
  )
ph_test
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable ph.test_p.value row_type
#>   <chr>    <chr>           <chr>   
#> 1 age      0.8             label   
#> 2 marker   0.6             label

mod %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  # merge in PH test p-values
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      dplyr::left_join(
        ph_test,
        by = c("variable", "row_type")
      )
  ) %>%
  # assign label to PH Test p-value
  modify_header(ph.test_p.value = "**PH Test**") %>%
  # convert to kable to display on StackOverflow
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **HR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** | **PH Test** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 1.01 | 0.99, 1.02 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.96 | 0.76, 1.21 | 0.7 | 0.6 |

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! Verified and works really well.
I just have a problem in a specific situation When I have a categorical variable. If I take your example and replace marker with grade, we can see the problem. PH test value is ok only for age. Ideally I would like to have the values of the PH test for the two grade categories (II and III) and also for the entire grade category (cox.zph(terms = TRUE)).
I'm new to R so I apologize if my questions are basic.
Thank you very much for this wonderful package and for your answers

Comment: In that case, you'll want to merge on term instead of variable to get p-values for the levels. Take a look at the data frame in side the gtsummary object `.$table_body`. You just need to create a data frame of PH p-values that can be merged with this data frame.